# delete all characters in line after certain string

Tags: bash, sed, awk

Hi I have the following file:

```
>seq0 id345
FQTWEEFSRAAEKLYLADPMKVRVVLKYRHVDGNLCIKVTDDLVCLVYRTDQAQDVKKIEKF
>seq1 id1045
KYRTWEEFTRAAEKLYQADPMKVRVVLKYRHCDGNLCIKVTDDVVCLLYRTDQAQDVKKIEKFHSQLMRLME
```

and I am trying to remove any character after the > so i get:

```
>
FQTWEEFSRAAEKLYLADPMKVRVVLKYRHVDGNLCIKVTDDLVCLVYRTDQAQDVKKIEKF
>
KYRTWEEFTRAAEKLYQADPMKVRVVLKYRHCDGNLCIKVTDDVVCLLYRTDQAQDVKKIEKFHSQLMRLME
```

I have almost got this using:

```
sed -e 's/>.*//'
```

however this also deletes the > symbols leaving me with:

```
FQTWEEFSRAAEKLYLADPMKVRVVLKYRHVDGNLCIKVTDDLVCLVYRTDQAQDVKKIEKF

KYRTWEEFTRAAEKLYQADPMKVRVVLKYRHCDGNLCIKVTDDVVCLLYRTDQAQDVKKIEKFHSQLMRLME
```

how do i keep the > characters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A re-usable solution for more complicated cases (using a capturing group):

```
sed -r 's/(>).*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest fix would be:

```
sed 's/>.*/>/'
```